# Git using the wrong SSH key

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-agent

I was using an SSH key for github for a while, I've now switched to a new account and Git is still trying to use my old SSH key. Here's what I get when trying to push:

```
remote: Permission to ***REPO*** denied to ***OLD USERNAME***
fatal: unable to access ***REPO***: The requested URL returned error: 403
```

My .gitconfig file has the correct email and name.

My ~\.ssh\config file reads as follows:

```
Host github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519   ***The correct key***
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I deleted the old key files.

When I run ssh-add -l, the only key listed is the correct one.

I also uninstalled and reinstalled Git.

Does anyone have any insights? Is there a global config file for ssh-agent somewhere or something?
I have no idea what to do, the only next step I can think of is literally reinstalling Windows.

Comment: `403` is an https error code, which means you're not using ssh in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you are using an SSH URL:

```
ssh://git@github.com/<newUser>/myproject
# or
git@github.com:<newUser>/myproject
```

So:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git remote -v
```

If you were to use an HTTPS URL, then it is possible the old user name/password is cached by the credential helper (check the value of `git config  --global credential.helper`)